# Racket Programming. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: scheme, racket, primes, prime-factoring

The question i'm trying to answer:
The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Where am I going wrong? my prime? test seems to be the issue, but it works fine on relatively small numbers. However the prime? test gives a wrong answer with larger numbers.  Is there an easier way to go about this?

```lisp
    (define b 3)

    (define z 0)

    (define divides?
      (lambda (a b)
        (= (remainder a b) 0)))

    (define (prime? n)
        (cond
          ((or (= n 1) (= n 0)) false)
          ((even? n) false)
          ((= n 2) true)
          ((= n b) true)
          ((divides? n b) false)
          (else (and (set! b (+ b 1)) (prime? n)))))

    ;Largest Prime Factor Test
    (define (LPF x)
      (cond
        ((divides? 600851475143 x)
         (cond
           ((prime? x)
            (cond
              ((> x z) (set! z x)))))))
      (if (< x 775146) (LPF (+ x 1)) (display z)))
```

Comment: Mutable variables make it hard to reason, and it's precisely where your `prime?` function is breaking: `b` is not being reset between calls to `prime?`.  But you shouldn't even be using global mutable variables here.  Use a temporary variable that is local to the function.  e.g. `(define (prime? n) (define (iter b) <body-of-your-function>) (iter 3))`.  If you're using `set!`, you have a host of issues you must think about.  Better to avoid `set!` if you can.

Comment: To demonstrate why your `prime?` is broken, do the following sequence and observe the result: `(prime? 7)` `(prime? 9)`.  You should see immediately that there's something funky.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Writing in a certain pseudocode, your intent seems to be

```
 pe3 = last [x | x <- [2 .. 775146], isPrime x, rem 600851475143 x == 0]
```

read it: *for `x` drawn from range 2 to 775146, if `isPrime x` holds, if `600851475143 % x` is 0, collect such `x`; return the largest*. We also write the application `(g x)` without the parentheses here, as just `g x`.

Calculating a remainder is cheaper than testing for primality, so we'll swap the two operations:

```
pe3 n = last [x | x <- [2 .. isqrt n], rem n x == 0, isPrime x]
```

This algorithm might work for the specific numbers involved, but unfortunately it is incorrect in general - say for 9000009, whose integer square root is 3000, it will return 101. But *9901* is the right answer (i.e. 9901 is the biggest prime divisor of 9000009, not 101).

Let's first focus on finding the *smallest* prime factor, instead:

```
pe3a n = head ([x | x <- [2 .. isqrt n], rem n x == 0, isPrime x] ++ [n])
```

Why the `( ... ++ [n])` (`++` meaning the concatenation of lists)?? Because if `n` itself is prime, no divisor will be found at all, and the first list will come back empty, `[]`. In which case the answer must be `n` itself. But if not, then the answer is the first (i.e. `head`) of the divisors list. Of course when we find it, we don't need to continue searching for more. Just one is enough, if the smallest is all we need.

OK, so trying it (at an imaginary lazy pseudocode interpreter), we get 3 as its first factor:

```
> pe3a 9000009
3
```

Now we can divide that 3 out of our number:

```
> div 9000009 3 
3000003
```

and continue with 3000003, instead of 9000009. That means we can stop at *its* square root, 1732, instead of at 3000 - a sizable gain in efficiency! Also, we don't need to start over from 2 - it was tested already - we can start from the last found factor:

```
pe3b (start, n) = (d, div n d)
  where
     d = head ([x | x <- [start .. isqrt n], rem n x == 0, isPrime x] ++ [n])

> pe3b (3, 3000003)
(3,1000001)
```

so we get a second 3 back, and the number is divided by the found divisor once again.

```
> pe3b (3, 1000001)
(101,9901)
```

the next prime divisor found is 101, and the number to factorize now is 1000001 / 101 = 9901. Again we start from the last found divisor, 101, because all the smaller ones were already tried:

```
> pe3b (101, 9901)
(9901,1)
```

Interesting. `isqrt(9901) == 99`, the list `[101 .. 99]` is empty, and so the result was immediately produced. 9901 is the first factor of itself above 100, and in fact above 1, because all the previous numbers were already tried, in succession, and divided out of it. That means 9901 is a prime, no need to test it for primality.

In fact, all factors found by this algorithm **are guaranteed to be prime by construction** by the same reasoning, and all the calls to `isPrime` were superfluous.

Do also take note that the biggest number for which the division (the remainder operation) was performed here, was 101 - *not* 3000. Not only our new algorithm is correct, it is also much more efficient!

Now you can code in Scheme this algorithm of repeated `pe3b` application and dividing by the last found factor. Stop when 1 is reached.

---

So, in [the same pseudocode](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction#Quicksort_in_Haskell),

```hs
divStep (start, n) = (d, div n d) 
  where d = head ([x | x <- [start .. isqrt n], rem n x == 0] ++ [n])

pe3 n = fst . until ((== 1) . snd) divStep $ (2,n)  -- (1st,2nd) in a tuple

factorizing n = takeWhile ((> 1) . fst) . drop 1 . iterate divStep $ (2,n)

factors n = map fst . factorizing $ n

isPrime n = factors n == [n]
```

Read `.` and `$` as "of". `until` *pred step start* is a higher-order pattern of repeated applications of a function, until a predicate is fulfilled ( `((== 1) . snd)` means that the second component of a result equals 1). It is usually coded in Scheme with named `let`.

To see the whole history of computation, `iterate` *step start* is another pattern which collects all the interim results (and the starting value, which we don't need, so we `drop` it). To see just the factors themselves, we take the first components of each result with `map fst`. A number is prime if it's the only divisor, greater than 1, of itself. Testing:

```hs
> pe3 9000009
9901
> factorizing 9000009
[(3,3000003),(3,1000001),(101,9901),(9901,1)]
> factors 9000009
[3,3,101,9901]

> pe3 600851475143
6857
> factorizing 600851475143
[(71,8462696833),(839,10086647),(1471,6857),(6857,1)]   -- 1471 is the largest
> factors 600851475143                                  --   factor tried, 
[71,839,1471,6857]                                      --   *not* 775146 !!

> factors 600851475143999917      -- isqrt 600851475143999917 == 775146099
[41,37309,392798360393]           -- isqrt 392798360393       ==    626736
```

Comment: @DanielFischer you mean "readable". :) Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/15691984/849891? Notice the year. :) Haskell really *is* lazy Scheme with types (and syntax). Lisp/Scheme's answer to how-to-parse: ***don't***.

Comment: cf. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Testing_primality#Primality_Test_and_Integer_Factorization for a one-liner `factors` using `unfoldr` instead of `iterate` (using [nice `listToMaybe` trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24003865/849891) from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003319/prime-factorization-using-list-comprehension/24003865#comment37007294_24003865)).

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer:

```
$ factor 600851475143
600851475143: 71 839 1471 6857
```

More serious answer: Your `prime?` function is indeed broken; I'm not even certain what it's trying to do. (Also, your `(= n 2)` test is too late to be useful: the `(even? n)` test has trumped it.)

My suggestion: Implement the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Here's [my implementation](https://gist.github.com/cky/4532978).