# Prime factors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, factorization, prime-factoring

I'm new to Haskell.

How to generate a list of lists which contains prime factors of next integers?

Currently, I only know how to generate prime numbers:

```
primes = map head $ iterate (\(x:xs) -> [y | y<-xs, y `mod` x /= 0 ]) [2..]
```

Comment: How far have you got? For example you could try writing a function to factorize a single number.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A simple approach to determine the prime factors of `n` is to

- search for the first divisor `d` in `[2..n-1]`
- if D exists: return `d : primeFactors(div n d)`
- otherwise return `n` (since `n` is prime)

**Code:**

```
prime_factors :: Int -> [Int]

prime_factors 1 = []
prime_factors n
  | factors == []  = [n]
  | otherwise = factors ++ prime_factors (n `div` (head factors))
  where factors = take 1 $ filter (\x -> (n `mod` x) == 0) [2 .. n-1]
```

This obviously could use a lot of optimization (search only from 2 to sqrt(N), cache the prime numbers found so far and compute the division only for these etc.)

**UPDATE**

A slightly modified version using case (as suggested by @user5402):

```
prime_factors n =
  case factors of
    [] -> [n]
    _  -> factors ++ prime_factors (n `div` (head factors))
  where factors = take 1 $ filter (\x -> (n `mod` x) == 0) [2 .. n-1]
```

Comment: instead of `factors == []`, it is more idiomatic (and perhaps more efficient) to use `case factors of [] -> ...`

Comment: note that `foo == []` introduces an `Eq` constraint in the type of `foo` (which is actually not needed here) while `case foo of [] -> ...` does not.

Comment: An alternative to `factors == []` but still using guards would be to just use `null factors` instead.

Comment: there is no need too check all [2..n-1] numbers. You can only check all [2..sqrt(n)], because if p | n, then p <= sqrt(n).

Comment: @RottenBrain I know (I mentioned it in my answer as a possible optimization) - I didn't want to spoil the fun for the OP :-)

Comment: @Frank Schmitt, oh sorry. You really have mentioned this optimisation :)

Comment: without the sqrt it's just terrible, and even with it it's suboptimal.

Comment: @WillNess Then please go ahead and post your own optimized solution :-)

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23944933/849891. :) Also, http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Testing_primality#Primality_Test_and_Integer_Factorization. (and much more verbose http://stackoverflow.com/a/15703327/849891)

Comment: @WillNess Impressive. Although I think that for repeated isPrime() calls for large numbers, a solution with memoization of the prime numbers found so far should be faster.

Comment: (also, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003319/prime-factorization-using-list-comprehension#comment37007294_24003865 - a nice one-liner, though also suboptimal).

Comment: btw your code can be written shorter and equivalently as `unfoldr (\n -> listToMaybe [(x, div n x) | x<- [2..n], mod n x==0])`.

Comment: @d12frosted "because if p | n, then p <= sqrt(n)", but number 5424684 has a prime factor 6367 which is larger than (sqrt 5424684 = ~2329). Or did I miss the point?

Comment: @Dai A number may very well have a prime factor that is larger than its square root. But: if a number n has a prime factor f1 which is greater than its square root, it must have at least one other prime factor f2 which is smaller than its square root (since n = f1*f2*<other factors>, and if f2 was also larger than sqrt(n), then the following would hold: `f1*f2 > sqrt(n) * f2 > sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = n`, which contradicts the assumption that f1 and f2 are prime factors of n.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Thanks for the explanation! So we recursively divide n by the factor smaller than sqrt n, thus never need to check numbers beyond sqrt n.

Comment: @Dai Exactly.  _this_comment_was_too_short_

Answer (score 6):

This is a good-performanced and easy-to-understand implementation, in which `isPrime` and `primes` are defined recursively, and `primes` will be cached by default. `primeFactors` definition is just a proper use of `primes`, the result will contains continuous-duplicated numbers, this feature makes it easy to count the number of each factor via `(map (head &&& length) . group)` and it's easy to unique it via `(map head . group)` :

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
primes :: [Int]

isPrime n | n < 2 = False
isPrime n = all (\p -> n `mod` p /= 0) . takeWhile ((<= n) . (^ 2)) $ primes
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3..]

primeFactors :: Int -> [Int]
primeFactors n = iter n primes where
    iter n (p:_) | n < p^2 = [n | n > 1]
    iter n ps@(p:ps') =
        let (d, r) = n `divMod` p
        in if r == 0 then p : iter d ps else iter n ps'
```

And the usage:

```
> import Data.List
> import Control.Arrow

> primeFactors 12312
[2,2,2,3,3,3,3,19]

> (map (head &&& length) . group) (primeFactors 12312)
[(2,3),(3,4),(19,1)]

> (map head . group) (primeFactors 12312)
[2,3,19]
```

Answer (score 6):

Until the dividend `m` < 2,

1. take the first divisor `n` from primes.
2. repeat dividing `m` by `n` while divisible.
3. take the next divisor `n` from primes, and go to 2.

The list of all divisors actually used are prime factors of original `m`.

**Code:**

```
-- | prime factors
--
-- >>> factors 13
-- [13]
-- >>> factors 16
-- [2,2,2,2]
-- >>> factors 60
-- [2,2,3,5]
--
factors :: Int -> [Int]
factors m = f m (head primes) (tail primes) where
  f m n ns
    | m < 2 = []
    | m `mod` n == 0 = n : f (m `div` n) n ns
    | otherwise = f m (head ns) (tail ns)

-- | primes
--
-- >>> take 10 primes
-- [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29]
--
primes :: [Int]
primes = f [2..] where f (p : ns) = p : f [n | n <- ns, n `mod` p /= 0]
```

**Update:**

This replacement code improves performance by avoiding unnecessary evaluations:

```
factors m = f m (head primes) (tail primes) where
  f m n ns
    | m < 2 = []
    | m < n ^ 2 = [m]   -- stop early
    | m `mod` n == 0 = n : f (m `div` n) n ns
    | otherwise = f m (head ns) (tail ns)
```

`primes` can also be sped up drastically, as mentioned in [Will Ness's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276844/prime-factors-in-haskell/34977654?noredirect=1#comment58025920_34977654):

```
primes = 2 : filter (\n-> head (factors n) == n) [3,5..]
```

Comment: this code is slow twice over: in factors it doesn't stop at sqrt, and in primes it doesn't wait until sqr -- of a prime.

Comment: @WillNess 
Thanks to your advice, I can update code.
This code become faster significantly by adding only a guard.
Original code takes 15 seconds to factorize 599946, while updated code takes only 6 milliseconds.

Comment: great; you've improved your `factors` but not the `primes` which still is much too slow. compare your definition's speed with that of `2:filter (\n-> head (factors n) == ......` (complete the definition). :) can you find the reason for such a difference in speed? see also ["empirical orders of growth"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth).

Comment: @WillNess I understood what you intend to do, but I could not complete your code snippet. I feel sorry but can you show me `primes` you defined?

Comment: sure, it's `primes = 2:filter (\n-> head (factors n) == n) [3,5..]`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Haskell allows you to create infinite lists, that are mutually recursive. Let's take an advantage of this.

First let's create a helper function that divides a number by another as much as possible. We'll need it, once we find a factor, to completely eliminate it from a number.

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

-- Divide the first argument as many times as possible by the second one.
divFully :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
divFully n q | n `mod` q == 0   = divFully (n `div` q) q
             | otherwise        = n
```

Next, assuming we have somewhere the list of all primes, we can easily find factors of a numbers by dividing it by all primes less than the square root of the number, and if the number is divisible, noting the prime number.

```
-- | A lazy infinite list of non-trivial factors of all numbers.
factors :: [(Integer, [Integer])]
factors = (1, []) : (2, [2]) : map (\n -> (n, divisors primes n)) [3..]
  where
    divisors :: [Integer] -> Integer -> [Integer]
    divisors _ 1          = []   -- no more divisors
    divisors (p:ps) n
        | p^2 > n       = [n]  -- no more divisors, `n` must be prime
        | n' < n        = p : divisors ps n'    -- divides
        | otherwise     = divisors ps n'        -- doesn't divide
      where
        n' = divFully n p
```

Conversely, when we have the list of all factors of numbers, it's easy to find primes: They are exactly those numbers, whose only prime factor is the number itself.

```
-- | A lazy infinite list of primes.
primes :: [Integer]
primes = mapMaybe isPrime factors
  where
    -- |  A number is prime if it's only prime factor is the number itself.
    isPrime (n, [p]) | n == p  = Just p
    isPrime _                  = Nothing
```

The trick is that we start the list of factors manually, and that to determine the list of prime factors of a number we only need primes less then its square root. Let's see what happens when we consume the list of factors a bit and we're trying to compute the list of factors of 3. We're consuming the list of primes, taking 2 (which can be computed from what we've given manually). We see that it doesn't divide 3 and that since it's greater than the square root of 3, there are no more possible divisors of 3. Therefore the list of factors for 3 is `[3]`. From this, we can compute that 3 is another prime. Etc.

Answer (score 3):

I just worked on this problem. Here's my solution.

Two helping functions are

```
factors n = [x | x <- [1..n], mod n x == 0]
isPrime n = factors n == [1,n]
```

Then using a list comprehension to get all prime factors and how many are they.

```
prime_factors num = [(last $ takeWhile (\n -> (x^n) `elem` (factors num)) [1..], x) | x <- filter isPrime $ factors num]
```

where

```
x <- filter isPrime $ factors num
```

tells me what prime factors the given number has, and

```
last $ takeWhile (\n -> (x^n) `elem` (factors num)) [1..]
```

tells me how many this factor is.

**Examples**

```
> prime_factors 36    -- 36 = 4 * 9
[(2,2),(2,3)]

> prime_factors 1800  -- 1800 = 8 * 9 * 25
[(3,2),(2,3),(2,5)]
```

Answer (score 2):

More elegant code，use 2 and odd numbers to divide the number.

```
factors' :: Integral t => t -> [t]
factors' n
  | n < 0 = factors' (-n)
  | n > 0 = if 1 == n
               then []
               else let fac = mfac n 2 in fac : factors' (n `div` fac)
  where mfac m x
          | rem m x == 0 = x
          | x * x > m    = m
          | otherwise    = mfac m (if odd x then x + 2 else x + 1)
```

Comment: ``let fac = mfac n 2 in fac : factors' (n `div` fac)`` is suboptimal, always starts from 2, can start from the previous `fac`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version. Not as concise as the others, but I think it's very readable and easy to understand.

```hs
import Data.List

factor :: Int -> [Int]
factor n
  | n <= 1 = []
  | even n = 2 : factor(div n 2)
  | otherwise =
    let root = floor $ sqrt $ fromIntegral n
    in
      case find ((==) 0 . mod n) [3, 5.. root] of
        Nothing  -> [n]
        Just fac -> fac : factor(div n fac)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this code is ugly enough to drive a real Haskell programmer to tears, but it works in GHCI 9.0.1 to provide prime factors with a count of each prime factor.

```
import Data.List
factors n = [x | x <- [2..(n`div` 2)], mod n x == 0] ++ [n]
factormap n = fmap factors $ factors n
isPrime n = case factormap n of [a] -> True; _ -> False
primeList (x:xs) = filter (isPrime) (x:xs)
numPrimes n a = length $ (factors n) `intersect` (takeWhile ( <=n) $ iterate (a*) a)
primeFactors n = primeList $ factors n
result1 n = fmap (numPrimes n) (primeFactors n)
answer n =  ((primeFactors n),(result1 n))
```

Example:
ghci> answer 504

```
([2,3,7],[3,2,1])
```

The answer is a list of prime factors and a second list showing how many times each
prime factor is in the submitted number.