# Prime factorization using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, prime-factoring

I want to find all prime factors of a given number using only list comprehension method and/or `.` (function composition operator) in Haskell. I specifically want to avoid a recursive solution.

For example, `pfactors 120` must produce `[2,2,2,3,5]` output.

I tried:

```
pfactors n = [p | p <- [2..n], n `mod` p == 0, [d | d <- [1..p], p `mod` d == 0] == [1,p]]
```

But when I call `pfactors 120`, the result is `[2,3,5]`, not all prime factors.

Comment: factors n = [p | p <- [2..n], n `mod` p == 0, [d | d <- [1..p], p `mod` d == 0] == [1,p]]

Comment: But when I call pfactors 120, the result is [2,3,5], not all prime factors.

Comment: it has been already put.

Comment: Not what you have tried...

Comment: do you have a list of primes?

Comment: What you get is the list of *unique prime factors* of `n`, but as your example clearly shows, some factors occur *more than once*, and even if you did enumerate values several times, you wouldn't know how many times you have to do it to get all the multiple factors..

Comment: Because the problem is unsolvable.

Comment: Yes didierc, that's right. Some factors occurs more than one time. But there must be a solution. How can I list all the multiple factors with list comprehension?

Comment: Yes, I don't understand neither @luqui

Comment: Probably because of the initial lack of code from the OP.

Comment: I think so, I am new here, so I did not notice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
pfactors :: Integer -> [Integer]
pfactors n = [ p
             | p <- [2..n]                                  -- Possible factors
             , [d | d <- [1..p], p `mod` d == 0] == [1,p]   -- Are prime 
             , _ <- [ p | i <- [1..n], n `mod` p^i == 0] ]  -- Divisible powers
```

It's essentially the solution you have, but the difference is that it has an extra list comprehension at the end which contains as many elements as `p` factors into `n`.

*Disclaimer* I really wouldn't do it like this in reality.

**EDIT** I felt dirty writing the above, so for reference, this is something closer to what I would write:

```
pfactors' :: Int -> [Int]
pfactors' = unfoldr firstFactor
  where
    firstFactor n =
        listToMaybe [(f, n `div` f)
                    | f <- [2..n]
                    , n `mod` f == 0]
```

*Dependencies:* `Data.List (unfoldr)`, `Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)`

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected, but shouldn't you filter to keep only the highest powers of each `p`?

Comment: Great @asQuirrel. That's my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @didierc, I don't believe so. What I'm doing here is keeping all the powers of `p` that divide `n` (by definition, these will be the smallest powers).

Comment: Yeah, *all the powers*, but strictly speaking, shouldn't you only return the highest ones? (I say strictly, because one can always filter them afterwards, so your answer is ok).

Comment: I agree with you @asQuirrel. Recursive solution is the best one. But I was wondering whether it is possible with this method. Everything is possible with you:) Thanks.

Comment: @didierc, I'm still not following you, if you're talking about the value for p, it is checked for primality first, if you are talking about the last part (what I added), then the values  are discarded, all we were actually interested in was the number of powers.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I did not understand your code. Very clever.

Comment: very nice `listToMaybe` trick!.. Though your formulation is inefficient; it should be ``factors n = unfoldr g (2,n) where g (d, n) = listToMaybe [(x, (x, div n x)) | n > 1, x <- [d..isqrt n]++[n], rem n x == 0]``. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15703327/849891). :)

Comment: Very nice, that's the solution I was aiming for :)

Comment: it's still suboptimal: it tests by all numbers instead of by primes only (precalculating the primes takes time but is worth it when doing more than a few calls to `factors`). cf. http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Testing_primality#Primality_Test_and_Integer_Factorization . But at least the deficiency is not *quadratic*...