# Improving naive qsort implementation

Tags: haskell, quicksort

I am starting to learn Haskell and I've been reading [this](https://wiki.haskell.org/Why_Haskell_Matters) page on Haskell's wiki, which reports this qsort implementation:

```
 qsort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
 qsort []     = []
 qsort (x:xs) = qsort less ++ [x] ++ qsort more
     where less = filter (<x)  xs
           more = filter (>=x) xs
```

followed by a warning that this is not the most efficient way to do it, and linking an [article](http://augustss.blogspot.it/2007/08/quicksort-in-haskell-quicksort-is.html) which shows an incredibly verbose version of the same algorithm. Just by looking at it, I though that that was *not* what I was learning Haskell for, and I wanted to make a better version of the initial qsort without sacrificing its elegance. I mostly concentrated on eliminating the need to run `filter` twice every call, and this is what I've come up:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
filter' _ [] = ([], [])
filter' f a = filterInternal a ([], [])
  where
    filterInternal [] p = p
    filterInternal (x:xs) (l, t)
      | f x       = filterInternal xs (x:l, t)
      | otherwise = filterInternal xs (l, x:t)

qsort' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
qsort' [] = []
qsort' (x:xs) = qsort' less ++ [x] ++ qsort' more
  where
    (more, less) = filter' (>x) xs
```

But I am not sure this is really better. I mean, it works, but how does it compare to the initial version?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of doing FP to avoid side-effects and, by extension, in-place algorithms?

Comment: The "problem" seems to be that some people believe that you can't call it "quicksort" if it isn't an in-place algorithm. For some reason.

Comment: [1] [The author of that post](http://stackoverflow.com/users/649287/augustss) was just having fun implementing the in-place quicksort in a way that looks a lot like C. [2] A second inefficiency of the one-liner quicksort is using `(++)` to build the intermediate lists. [3] For an efficient implementation without mutability, you can look at the [`qsort` commented out in `Data.List`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/Data-OldList.html#sort), which amusingly was originally written by Lennart Augustsson as well.

Comment: Wait, isn't he the one behind Haskell as well? Man... I should't have let that glob of code frighten me that much...

Comment: Note that your `filter'` function already exists as `partition` in the `Data.List` module.

Comment: Yeah, I had the feeling I was re-doing something already implemented, but as I said, I am currently learning Haskell; I took this as an exercise of functional-thinking :)

Comment: For "how does it compare functionally", try [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck). For "how does it compare in speed", try [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Comment: I shall do it as soon as I have a Haskell compiler available! Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I came up with when pondering roughly the same problem (please point out any caveats!). I haven't thought too much about the space-complexity (shouldn't be too terrible though), just the time. The thing that really kills the naive `qsort` is the `O(n)` operation `(++)`. So, lets use a new data structure (which will be foldable) that gives us fast concatenation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

import Data.Foldable
import Data.List

data Seq a = (Seq a) :++: (Seq a) | Leaf a | Empty deriving (Foldable)
```

Then, a modified `qsort'` that returns a `Seq a` would be

```
qsort' :: Ord a => [a] -> Seq a
qsort' []     = Empty
qsort' (x:xs) = qsort less :++: Leaf x :++: qsort more
    where (less, more) = partition (<x)  xs
```

And `qsort` itself is then just `qsort = toList . qsort'`.

Note: the fix involving `partition` gets you a constant factor better, but the `++` vs `:++:` means that `qsort` can now be better than `O(n^2)`. Also, most sort implementations out there are better than this. The point of this was only to try to mirror as closely as possible the "naive" implementation.

Comment: The real problem is not even `(++)`, but the fact that `(++)` doesn't freely re-associate across recursive calls to `qsort`. This problem can be fixed without defining a new data structure with the standard "difference list" trick. The idea is that we manipulate partially-applied `(++)` calls (of type `[a] -> [a]`) rather than flat lists (of type `[a]`); thus: `qsort :: Ord a => [a] -> ([a] -> [a]); qsort [] = id; qsort (x:xs) = qsort less . (x:) . qsort more where { ... }`. (`id = ([]++)` and `(x:) = ([x]++)`.) This reassociates all the `(++)` operations to the right, the efficient direction.

Comment: Equivalently to @DanielWagner's suggestion, use [`Data.DList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist-0.3/docs/Data-DList.html) to build the intermediate lists, which provides a nice abstract interface so you don't even have to see any details of the trick.

Comment: Actually the time taken by `(++)` has no effect on the asymptotic complexity of even the original `qsort`. At each level the amount of time it takes to recombine the pieces with `(++)` is no more than it already took to split apart the pieces with `partition`.

Comment: [here's another version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641936/is-it-possible-to-do-quicksort-of-a-list-with-only-one-passing/9550430#9550430) of it that's supposed to be faster.

Comment: @ReidBarton yes, it adds O(n^2) ops where it's already O(n^2); but it could've been O(n), so it's bound to affect constant factors.

Comment: Of course it makes a constant factor difference, but the last paragraph of this answer claims it makes an asymptotic difference. And it's a fairly popular misconception.